# Not tradable custom SPL-token

Tags: spl-token, rust

It is possible to create a custom SPL-token and disabling the trade and send capabilities for the user (not for the SPL-token authority)? The idea is to create a token that can only be purchased and spent within our specific application and at the same time maintain all the benefits of an SPL-token. Is it possible to do this, or do you know any alternative that I can use?

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to manage the tokens entirely, you can go with the `managed-token` approach, which keeps the token frozen at all times, and must pass through your program, which thaws, does something (burn / transfer / etc), and re-freezes the account.

You can find the source code for a reference implementation at https://github.com/solana-labs/solana-program-library/tree/master/managed-token/program

Answer (score 0):

I think it's only a way to build a new program, which will hold the SPL-token owned by the PDA derived from the program. You can add the specific instructions by your own business logic, like deposit/withdraw/send etc.
For UX, furthermore, you'll be developing application-specific wallet to display the balance and drive the user's actions.

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but I need it to meet SPL-token standards so I can use it in other programs. Do you know if there is any way to modify the SPL-token source code?

Comment: Of course, you can modify the SPL-token program on your own. But one thing you should make sure is the program existing on chain. You must deploy the customized SPL-token program with new program id.

Comment: And if I do that, the tokens created with my custom SPL-token will be compatible with programs that use SPL-token (for example with the anchor_spl::token library).